# Trying to download a file from google colab - Showing index error

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
from google.colab import files

filename= os.listdir('/content/Real-ESRGAN/results')

files.download('/content/Real-ESRGAN/results/'+filename[0])
```

Showing this error msg

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-9cd613c11ac6> in <module>()
      4 
      5 filename= os.listdir('/content/Real-ESRGAN/results')
----> 6 files.download('/content/Real-ESRGAN/results/'+filename[0])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You filename may not contain anything, it might be an empty list. check `print(filename)`

Answer (score 0):

What is likely happening is that your `filename` list is empty. Thus, it has no element at index 0, so your index is out of range.

Answer (score -1):

This code works perfectly for me:

```
for i in os.listdir('/content/youfolder') :    
#print(i) 
    files.download('/content/youfolder/'+i)
```